# How to copy a image file in Qt?

Tags: file, url, qt4, copy

I need to copy a number of image files from a given location to a given directory, i need the original filename preserved.

can it be something like 
url->copy(img14, ImgPath);

where img14 is the path to the file including the filename and the imgpath is the destination directory.

img14 can be : /home/obscurant1st/Downloads/aaa.jpeg
or C:\abcd\asada.jpeg

Plase Note: I have to use variables. I cannot use the exact path in the code!

Comment: What variables are you talking about? Do you mean environment variables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [QFile::copy](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfile.html#copy-2). Note that both parameters are full file paths, so you need to create the destination file path using the destination directory and source file name. And there [QFileInfo::fileName()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfileinfo.html#fileName) will probably be useful.

**Edit:**

Just create a function that gets the source file path and the destination directory:

```
bool CopyFile(const QString& sourceFile, const QString& destinationDir)
{
    QFileInfo fileInfo(sourceFile);
    QString destinationFile = destinationDir + QDir::separator() + fileInfo.fileName();
    bool result = QFile::copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I need to use variables! 
So this will not work.
As of now I am trying QProcess with StartDetached("cp", QStringList() << var << var2).

But if there is some other way without using the system commands, pls let me know! :)

Comment: You need to create a string variable that contains the full path.

Comment: thx man, now with this edited part it works excellent. :)
This is what i wanted!